# Using private domainname in cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I have my own private domain name and I would like use this domain name instead of a subdomain from "scapp.io" from the swisscom cloud foundry plattform. Is this possible? How can I achieve this? Which domain server from swisscom can I use and how can I add my DNS records? Is it also possible to use SSL certificates?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Create the domain in the ORGS part of the developer console (e.g. `yourdomain.ch`)
2. Create the route in the SPACES part of the developer console (e.g. `www.yourdomain.ch`)
3. Additionally, create a route on the public domain address (e.g. `yourapp.scapp.io`)
4. Map your app to **both of these routes** in the SPACES part of the developer console
5. Go to the management console of your service provider where you registered your domain (in my case this is a Parallels Plesk portal from the web hosting provider)
6. Add a CNAME DNS entry for your domain `yourdomain.ch` with the name `www` and the target `yourapp.scapp.io` (note that you may or may not need to add a dot at the end: `yourapp.scapp.io.`, this depends on your provider)

This way, a request to `www.yourdomain.ch` is (transparently) routed to `yourapp.scapp.io`. Worked well for me.

According to recent news, SSL with **Let's Encrypt** should now be possible, which is fantastic news. However, I was not able to activate it yet.

Answer (score 0):

See [Routes and Domains](http://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html) about detailed instructions. I recommend docs.developer.swisscom.com, there should be all use cases described.

> Domains in App Cloud provide a namespace from which to create routes.
>   The presence of a domain in App Cloud indicates to a developer that
>   requests for any route created from the domain will be routed to App
>   Cloud. This provision requires DNS to be configured out-of-band to
>   resolve the domain name to the IP address of a load balancer
>   configured to forward requests to the CF routers.

At the moment SSL certificates are not possible, but it's on the road map. Please read the newsletter for future announcement.